# My bootstrap collapse isn't toggling and closing correctly on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two buttons ('x', 'cancel') in a bootstrap collapse that should toggle and close the collapsable. The first button which is shown as a 'x' works fine and closes the collapsable but the 'cancel' doesn't close the collapsable region. Any thoughts on why? Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2ant1fs/) I tried setting up.
Another issue is that when the 'x' closes the collapsable region then I open it again the bootstrap well is missing. Any ideas why this is?

```js
$(document).on("click", "button.cancel-student-button", function() {
  var collapse = $(this).closest("collapse");
  $(collapse).collapse('toggle');
});
```

```html
<div class="collapse cborder" id=cancellation style="position:relative">
  <div class="unregster-student-well well" style="margin-bottom: 0; border: 1px solid yellowgreen;">
    <div class="unregister-student-alert alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="cancel-student-button close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
      </button>
      <h4>Oh snap! You want to unregister as a student!</h4>
      <p>Press the unregister button and you will be automatically unregistered from this YogaBandy event.</p>
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Unregister</button>
        <button type="button" class="cancel-student-button btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Correct your code as such: var collapse = $(this).closest(".collapse"); You were missing a dot before collapse word.

Comment: got it thanks. but I'm still having an issue with clicking the 'x' it for some reason removes the well data so when I open it again the collapsable region is empty

Comment: Maybe it is because you are using data-dismiss="alert" on it, so by clicking the X button bootstrap js file will look for alert to dismiss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few things that should be changed:

1) Your data target has no parenthesis around it: `id=cancellation`.

2) `closest("collapse");` requires a period to denote a the class

3) You don't need `button` here > `".cancel-student-button"`

4) And remove `data-dismiss="alert"`.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".cancel-student-button", function() {
  var collapse = $(this).closest(".collapse");
  $(collapse).collapse('toggle');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#cancellation" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Button with data-target</button>
<div class="collapse cborder" id="cancellation" style="position:relative">
  <div class="unregster-student-well well" style="margin-bottom: 0; border: 1px solid yellowgreen;">
    <div class="unregister-student-alert alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="cancel-student-button close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>

      </button>
      <h4>Oh snap! You want to unregister as a student!</h4>

      <p>Press the unregister button and you will be automatically unregistered from this YogaBandy event.</p>
      <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Unregister</button>
        <button type="button" class="cancel-student-button btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```